# Viewpager on portrait and two panes on landscape

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-configchanges

I'm trying to achieve a layout that shows a view pager when the device is shown on portrait and show two panes when device is on landscape.

So I made two different layout files, one with only a ViewPager, the other with a LinearLayout and the other with two FrameLayouts, I don't think it is necessary to show them here. There is also a boolean value `hasTwoPanes` for the two configurations.

```
@Inject FragmentOne fragmentOne;
@Inject FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean hasTwoPanes = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.hasTwoPanes);

    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    if (hasTwoPanes) {
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        tabLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(fm));
    }

    FragmentOne frag1 = (FragmentOne) fm.findFragmentByTag(getFragmentName(0));
    if (frag1 != null) fragmentOne = frag1;

    FragmentTwo frag2 = (FragmentTwo) fm.findFragmentByTag(getFragmentName(1));
    if (frag2 != null) fragmentTwo = frag2;

    if (hasTwoPanes) {
        if (frag1 != null) {
            fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragmentOne).commit();
            fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragmentTwo).commit();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
        }

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_frag1, fragmentOne, getFragmentName(0)).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_frag2, fragmentTwo, getFragmentName(1)).commit();
    }
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return fragmentOne;
        } else {
            return fragmentTwo;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}

private static String getFragmentName(int pos) {
    return "android:switcher:" + R.id.view_pager + ":" + pos;
}
```

Two fragments are injected with Dagger. If no fragments were already present, these injected fragments are added to the view pager or the layout depending on the orientation.

Because the view pager adapter gives a name to its fragments, I need to know that name (hence `getFragmentName(int pos)` method) to get back that fragment after rotation.

The result is state is correctly restored when rotating from portrait to landscape, but when rotating from landscape the portrait, the view pager is completely empty. When I rotate back to landscape, the fragments reappear. The tab layout is also buggy, there is no swipe animation, I can just continuously slide from one tab to the other, stopping anywhere.

To clarify things, this is happening in an Activity, there is no parent fragment. Even though the fragments are not shown, the fragment's `onViewCreated` is called. The view pager seems to correctly restore the fragment references in `instantiateItem`. Also, when debugging, fragments have the `added` to true and `hidden` to false. This make it seem like a view pager rendering issue.

- How do I make the view pager show my fragments?
- Is there a better way to achieve the behavior I want?

Comment: If isTablet show dual pane in a landscape mode else it is mobile device, show portrait mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found is very simple, override `getPageWidth` in my pager adapter like this:

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    boolean hasTwoPanes = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.hasTwoPanes);
    return hasTwoPanes ? 0.5f : 1.0f;
}
```

`R.bool.hasTwoPanes` being a boolean resources available in default configuration and `values-land`. My layout is the same for both configuration, and the tab layout is simply hidden on landscape.

The fragment restoration is done automatically by the view pager.

Comment: What is default value of hasTwoPanes?

Comment: @Stanojkovic `false` by default and `true` on landscape.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using PagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter? You will get better control over creation and handling of fragments. Otherwise you dont know what is the FragmentPagerAdapter doing (hes doing it for you, but probably wrong).

You cam move much of that logic into that class making the activity cleaner, and probably also fix the problems you have.

EDIT: Since we are talking orientation changes here, you should probably incorporate `onConfigurationChanged` callback to handle that logic better.

Comment: Yes, I've thought about it, I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Portrait Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Landscape Xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Java:

```
package com.dev4solutions.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.dev4solutions.myapplication.fragment.FragmentA;
import com.dev4solutions.myapplication.fragment.FragmentB;

public class FragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Point point = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag);
        if (point.y > point.x) {
            TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab);
            ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentA, new FragmentA())
                    .commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentB, new FragmentB())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not handle configuration changes, fragment will be lost on rotation.

Answer (score 1):

## ViewPager2 Configuration Change Handling for Portrait and Landscape Modes

If you're facing issues with `ViewPager2` during configuration changes, especially when transitioning between portrait and landscape modes, you can implement the following solution.

```java
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Check if the orientation has changed to landscape or portrait
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        // Save the current index for later use
        int currentIndex = index;

        // Set the ViewPager to the previous item, but not below the first item
        viewPager2.setCurrentItem(Math.max(index - 1, 0), false);

        // Reset the ViewPager to the original item to maintain the user's current position
        viewPager2.setCurrentItem(currentIndex, false);
    }
}
```

Make sure you have added this line in the Manifest file: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:exported="false" />
```